# Vaadin 14.5.3 Multiselectlistbox setvalue error

Tags: vaadin-flow, vaadin14

i tried with version 14.5.3. Setting the value on 2 occasion causes the 2nd instance and more not to be selected.

I did a sample project.

https://vaadin.com/attachment/b5b73b0f-dfef-45fa-88b9-197cb9d7545a/multiselectlistboxtest%20(2).zip

Opening a dialog should already set the multiselectlistbox to preselected values from the list.

Try changing the version to 14.3.7 and it will worked.

Does anyone know what is causing this?

Comment: Works for me. What is your problem?

Comment: The check boxes are selected when the dialog open in vaadin 14.3.7.
But in vaadin 14.5.3 it does not. Check out the sample images.

https://vaadin.com/attachment/ad80b723-c7c8-45f2-8d3a-24be193aa428/vaadin%2014.3.7.gif

https://vaadin.com/attachment/029c05ba-511b-4b57-b4d2-44419ce88b66/vaadin%2014.5.3.gif

Comment: Ah I see how to reproduce. IMHO this is a bug. Please file an issue https://github.com/vaadin/flow-components/issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This issue](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-list-box/issues/94) is fixed in Vaadin 14.6.0.rc1.